# Populate Textbox Value based on Dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can populate the value of a textbox based on their selection of a drop-down option? The dropdown list has values from Field1 then  textbox will retrieve its corresponding value from Field2

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us, and remember that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: You need to be much more clear in what it is you're actually trying to do; stating *Field1* and *Field2* plus the *php*, *mysql* and *ajax* tags make me suspect that you're attempting to load a `<select>` list from the database (*Field1*) with an `onchange` action that retrieves the corresponding value from the database (*Field2*) via Ajax and put that value into a `<textarea>` ... but that is *just a guess*.

Comment: @CD001 yes exactly your guess is correct!

Comment: Oki - and which bit of that are you having problems with? If it's *all of it* then the question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correctly then want you want is to set the value of the text box on selecting the selectbox. well you can do this by using javascript
here is the code that will work fine in your case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select box</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select onchange="change_subject(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select subject</option>
        <option value="hindi">hindi</option>
        <option value="maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="main_text">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_subject(str){
        document.getElementById("main_text").value=str;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your code it's working well for me. but actually, I want to retrieve values from the database ... assume,  when I selecting the drop-down "category" (IT, CS etc) options then it will fill their relevant mobile number field value in the textbox.

Comment: you can use this str value and send the ajax request to the server and then fetch the result you want is easy  check out  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp for understand the ajax functionality